# Creating SVG markers for PolyLine in alternative points. (Step curve)

Tags: javascript, svg, markers, polyline

I am creating a polyline as a step curve. I want the markers to placed on at the point of significance and not at every end of the lines of the steps. How do i accomplish this?

```
            <polyline points="0,0 140,125 160,140 180,220 220,240 300,280 400,450    500,500 900,900"
                      style="fill: none;" 
                      stroke="blue"
                      stroke-width="5" 
                      marker-start="url(#point)" 
                      marker-mid="url(#point)" 
                      marker-end="url(#point)"
                      clip-path="url(#clip)" />
            <defs>
                <marker id="point" viewbox="0 0 10 10" refx="5" refy="5" markerwidth="10" markerheight="10"
                    orient="auto" markerUnits = "userSpaceOnUse">
                    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="1" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" fill="black">
                    </circle>
                </marker>
            </defs>
        </g>
```

I do not want to use two different SVG PolyLines to create the proper markers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to control which of the points in a line get markers, other than the coarse control provided by `marker-start`, `marker-mid` and `marker-end`.

Finer control is proposed for SVG2, but that doesn't help you now.

Your only solution is to add separate elements to the file for each of your points of interest.